# ASP MVC3 keeping variable value through page refresh

Tags: session, variables, refresh, asp.net-mvc

Yo! As the topic says, I need to keep var's value through refresh. Thing is it's SessionKey. Other thing is it's generated automatically.

What I need to do is html `<select>` which won't lose data on refresh. Actually there're 2 `<select>`s which are filled programatically and you can pass data between them in real time. Then if I press save and page fails to validate these `<select>`s return to their original state. I already have it fixed, by keeping data in session and if it has certain key, `<select>`s are filled with correct data.

Why would I need automatically generated key? Well multi-tab working. If user would try to add 2+ new records to database at the same time (which is extreme, but possible), he needs to have that data kept under different keys so app can find desired stuff.

I could as well make client side validation, but... nope, just nope, too much work.

As for code, anything useful:

```
public ActionResult MethodUsedAfterPageLoad
{
   ...
   Guid stronyGuid = Guid.NewGuid();
   ViewData["strony"] = stronyGuid.ToString();
   ...
}
```

This way every refresh creates new Guid, but Guid is used as SessionKey!

If I do it following way:

```
public Class ControllerClass
{
    private Guid stronyGuid;
    ...
}
```

This will reset variable, that's bad. Using `static` keyword is bad idea.

Comment: Could you garnish your question with some code to illustrate the problem?

Comment: Why don't you pass the Guid as action parameter?

Comment: Save button ain't ActionLink. Unless u mean something else, code example would be welcome. It's a legacy code, so changing that would mean too much work for some extreme case.

Comment: So Save button is a submit button? So you have an HTML `<form>`? Then you could include the Guid as a hidden field inside this form so that it gets submitted alongside the other values to the controller action.

Comment: Will change with every refresh then. Or won't be different for every instance of page.